# vite build gives unexpected token for svg in storybook node_modules dependency

Tags: reactjs, svg, storybook, vite

I am working on a project that uses vite to build a ssr version of a react app. I have a storybook components library which I import components from, it contains several assets mostly in the form of svgs. Everything works fine in development mode, but the final build produces the following error:

```
.../client/node_modules/storybook/dist/svg/flags/arabic.svg:1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../client/node_modules/storybook/dist/svg/flags/index.js:4:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
```

It appears as though it is trying to import the svg as though it were a js file. I've tried every suggestion I can find, I just struggle to fully understand why the problem occurs in the first place.

Note the storybook dependency is commonjs.

Here is my vite.config.js:

```
import * as path from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import rollupReplace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh';
import reactSvgPlugin from 'vite-plugin-react-svg';
import svgrPlugin from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        reactRefresh(),
        reactSvgPlugin(),
        svgrPlugin({
            svgrOptions: {
                icon: false
                // ...svgr options (https://react-svgr.com/docs/options/)
            }
        }),
        rollupReplace({
            preventAssignment: true,
            values: {
                __DEV__: JSON.stringify(true),
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
            }
        }),
        react()
    ],
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            external: 'src/entry.client.tsx'
        }
    },
    resolve: process.env.USE_SOURCE
        ? {
            alias: {
                'react-router': path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    '../../packages/react-router/index.tsx'
                ),
                'react-router-dom': path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    '../../packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx'
                )
            }
        }
        : {}
});
```

Comment: I think you might not need both vite-plugin-react-svg and vite-plugin-svgr, they both do the same thing, as far as I know.  Otherwise, both tools test for files ending with `.svg`, and it's possible vite is adding a query param to the end.  I'd suggest finding the plugin in node_modules, and logging the `id` and `result` just above this line, for example: https://github.com/visualfanatic/vite-svg/blob/7e1571bf0636b2f341d1e66c23e8e264e64cc156/packages/vite-plugin-react-svg/index.js#L53